# Ruby on Rails Webservice - access via ajax request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, cross-domain

i'm implementing a server in ruby on rails. Now i want to get some data out of this server using a ajax request (the client side is on another domain, so it's a cross-domain call) and receiving the data as JSON.

What do i have to do to get this working?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery on client side to send ajax requests:

Form a has of your params like this:

```
var data = {
                    remote: true,
                    myplace:
                    {
                        swlat:lat(),
                        swlng:lng(),
                        nelat:lat(),
                        nelng:lng(),

                    }
                };
    $.getJSON('/location/getNewLocation',data, function(postsData) {
       parseReturnedJsonData(postsData);

   });
```

This will send  a POST request to the URL for json data. And then on server, you can read params and then render json using jQuery in `parseReturnedJsonData()` function. Check getJson and parseJson functions from jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 0):

Look at `jsonp` for rails, but be sure you understand how [`jsonp`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) works

http://kevinchiu.org/archives/jsonp-in-rails-3

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pass `callback` as a query parameter:

```
  $.getJSON('http://some-service.com/some-resource?callback=?',data, function(postsData) {
    parseReturnedJsonData(postsData);
  });
```

Also, make sure the API you're querying supports JSONP. Check out http://eduvoyage.com/jsonp-explained.html for a better understanding of how JSONP works.